# Data packets from a port to MSMQ

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I am new to  MSMQ .  We have a situation where we have many c# applications(.exe)  sending data packets on a port. They can send the  data packets to a port . How can I configure MSMQ to automatically read from the port and post these data packets to MSMQ. We cannot afford to loose any of these data packets and so loss of data is not acceptable at all . How can this be done efficiently. Can MSMQ be configured to accept the data packets from port 1801  . If these applications we have  wrote to different ports will that be better ? Are if they wrote to one port , how can these messages be sent to the MSMQ directly with NO DATA LOSS.
 We want the queue to be transactional.  We dont want to use the data packets that arrive.

Please help .  Any sample code which can do this task will be of great help.

Please NOTE that the applications are written in  C# .NEt. Data loss and slow performance has been a problem and we are trying to solve them using MSMQ.  We must see all data packets from these applications in MSMQ.

Thanks

Comment: When working with MSMQ you normally would not need to cope with certain ports at all. Can you explain a bit more in why this is so important for you?

Comment: Ah, I re-read your question. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

*How can I configure MSMQ to automatically read from the port*

unless you are prepared to write code I don't think this is possible. So on the assumption that you don't mind a little bit of code for yourself, check out the [System.Messaging.Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.aspx) class. The Body property allows you to send in a byte array.

So provided you are reading from the port into some kind of byte array, putting it into a message should be a doddle.

Comment: Thanks . I dont mind writing code at all. I was just wondering if it can be done if port 1801 was used to get the data packets?  So should I have tcplistener and send messages to msmq? Will that be efficient - No data packet loss. Because now since we are getting these data packets and updating db, we are losing data packets in the meantime,

Comment: I read that WCF can be used . But how can I configure WCF to use a port to read data and send to MSMQ? I am really clueless. Please help

Comment: Whichever way you do it you've basically got two things going on. First, read the packets into memory (and I see no reason why you should encounter data loss if you do this properly), and second, send the message. Oh, and third a little bit of glue code to join the two bits together. The first and second tasks can be done with WCF as you say, and there are many examples of each on the web. contd...

Comment: ....Note though that as with any technology, WCF requires a learning curve. Don't get me wrong, it is good technology and well worth knowing, but if you are desparate to get something done *now* you might want to write something more bespoke and use the .net api directly.

Comment: for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx (haven't checked this too closely, but looks appropriate for the "listening to tcp" part of your problem). Like I say, if the intricacy in this example scares you, maybe wcf is not your best option right now.

Comment: Thanks again. I did go through the WCF tutorial. I was able to get the tutorial working. one doubt is will this work for only wcf clients? But  i have tcp clients( c#, java) sending data to a port. Will this service respond ?Also how to tie this with MSMQ ?

Comment: A tcp listener would work for any tcp client, basically because tcp / ip is as low as you can go. However this question becomes more interesting when you talk about MSMQ. WCF supports 2 MSMQ bindings, NetMsmqBinding and MsmqIntegrationBinding. NetMsmqBinding is designed to be used when both endpoints are WCF. So you should be looking at the other one...

Comment: as regards tieing to MSMQ, you're going to be writing a service which will pull data off this stream (using wcf or not), so at the end of the "listen" you'll have some kind of byte array in memory. As I said at the very top, you can simply set the body of your msmq message to be this byte array (using wcf or not). Tieing the two is the easy bit!

Answer (score 0):

> *How can this be done efficiently. Can MSMQ be configured to accept the
>   data packets from port 1801.
>   If these applications we have wrote to different ports will that be
>   better?*

1801 is already the **default port** for MSMQ **TCP** packets, see MSDN article [TCP ports, UDP ports, and RPC ports that are used by Message Queuing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178517).

If your port numbers are indeed important, you may configure the WCF service to listen on certain ports in its `address` part of the service configuration.

When working with MSMQ you normally do not have to deal with any special ports, except when configuring communication between multiple networks through firewalls (MSDN Article: [How To Configure a Firewall for MSMQ Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183293) ).

If possible, I would recommend to stick with the default values.

> *How can these messages be sent to the MSMQ directly with NO DATA LOSS.
>   We want the queue to be transactional.*

If you use transactional queues you secure the message automatically against data loss. More on this in [Queuing in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx) and [Reliable Messaging with MSMQ and .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx)

> *Data loss and slow performance has been a problem and we are trying to
>   solve them using MSMQ. We must see all data packets from these
>   applications in MSMQ.*

MSMQ itself is fast and lightweight, but as with every other tool, it all depends on what you do with it - and how. If you start sending large data packets, MSMQ might get into trouble, too. Keep in mind that MSMQ has some limitations, e.g. [for message size](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/08/22/why-is-there-a-4mb-limit-on-msmq-messages.aspx).

Here are articles/ tutorials to get you started with **WCF in combination with MSMQ**:

- MSDN: [MSMQ and WCF: Getting Started](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/motleyqueue/archive/2009/05/31/msmq-and-wcf-getting-started.aspx)
- [Message Queuing to Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751490)
- A more complete scenario with secured communation: [Creating a WCF Service with MSMQ Communication and Certificate
  Security](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326909/Creating-a-WCF-Service-with-MSMQ-Communication-and) (Code Project)

Comment: Thanks . Can WCF Servicewith nettcp binding , read data from a port ? How ?  If that is possible should I use the same service to dump that data to MSMQ? Is this possible. I did read the tutorials you suggested . But still I am not very clear.

Comment: @user180175: A WCF service listens to **any port** you configure it to. But this has nothing to do with how the service receives the queue-messages! I am sorry to say, it looks like the feeling that you did not fully grasp the workings of neither WCF nor MSMQ yet. Have a look at this article [How to: Exchange Queued Messages with WCF Endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789032.aspx), which axplains a WCF/ MSMQ scenario complete full source code. I hope that this sheds some light into the dark. :-)